# iMacros Runtime Error

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, imacros

I don't know what's wrong with the script, whenever I run this JS in iMacros (FireFox), it instantly closes the browser, instead of waiting for the 1st part of macro to complete, and then close window, by, window.close() command

```js
var macro, ret;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=New%20Folder%20(1)%5CCCmain.iim" + "\n";
var start;
start = iimPlay
main:
{
 for (j=1;j<=1;j++)
 {
 iimSet("j", j)
 ret=iimPlay(macro);window.close();
 if (ret == -101)
 {
 break main; 
 }
 if (ret == -990)
 {
  macro2 =  "CODE:";
  macro2 +=  "WAIT SECONDS = 60" + "\n"; 
  iimPlay(macro2)
 }
 }
}
```

Thanks to anyone who helps/tries to help.